# moment.js add doesn't add time

Tags: javascript, time, addition, momentjs

when I do

---- edit ----

```
var someMoment = moment('6:30 PM', ["h:mm A"]);
```

---- end edit ----

```
someMoment.add(30, 'minutes')
```

I don't seem to get any result.

```
console.log(start); -- Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "6:30 PM", _f: "h:mm A", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
console.log(start.add(inc, 'minutes')); --Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "6:30 PM", _f: "h:mm A", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
```

The docs say that add mutates the specified moment, so the above should work but I've also tried

```
var end = start.add(inc, 'minutes')
console.log(end); --Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "6:30 PM", _f: "h:mm A", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
```

what I can do though is this

```
console.log(start.add(inc, 'minutes').format("h:mm A")); --7:00 PM
```

What I want is to take a moment, add 30 minutes to it and, preferably have a new moment that is 30 minutes ahead, or at least have the initial moment be 30 minutes ahead.

I know I can take the format out put and put it in a new moment, and I guess I will but this seems kind of broken.

---- edit ----

using moment 2.1

I am getting this from within a method in my app, I haven't isolated it in a jsfiddle or anything, but the method takes a string and a increment.  I guess I'll paste it here

here i'm trying one way but I've also tried using the modified start and cloning the start

```
var timeIsBetweenStartInc = function(_target:string, _start:string, inc:int){
var target = moment(_target, ["h:mm A"]);
var start = moment(_start, ["h:mm A"]);
console.log(start);
var end = moment(start).add(inc, 'minutes');
console.log(end);

return target.isBetween(start, end, 'minutes', '[)');(target, start, end);
};
```

---- end edit ----

Comment: Can't replicate your error. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'll add some more detail. one moment. no pun intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moment.js has a `clone` method that you could use like this:

```
var now = moment(),
    future = now.clone();
```

And then you could add some time to the cloned moment:

```
future.add(30, "minutes");
```

Now if you compare the UNIX timestamps of the two moments...

```
future.unix() - now.unix();
```

You'll notice they're 1800 seconds = 30 minutes apart.

Comment: ok, this is the closest so far, when cloned explicitly ( I thought just doing moment(oldMoment); would clone it ) it does increment the _d value which is the whole time, but the _i value does not inc.  soooo, maybe the value _i ( which is what jumps out at you when looking at the console ) is the "original" time? or what was passed in or something?  So I need to check that the moment queries are acting on _d.  if so I may be fixed

Comment: ugg, ok so I didn't pay close enough attention.  It is incrementing the _d value but it's not cloning it so both the start and the end are both incremented

Comment: @Raif I think you're focussing too much on some internal properties. You should instead focus on the operations you want to perform (and be sure to read the docs to see how certain operations are supposed to work). I doubt that Moment.js is broken for "simple" operations.

Comment: OK, well you seem to be right, I have to trust the machine.  Despite what the internals say, the process does seem to work.  I just have that it's pretty misleading and disconcerting, but screw it, it works.

Comment: Everyone has been helpful, but since you are the one who said, "dude, it probably just works don't worry about what in inside" I will mark yours as the correct answer

Comment: Do not look at _d. It will not be right. We document this here: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/

Comment: Also potentially helpful: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/

Comment: Thanks @maggie.  It's a great product, I was just very frustrated because as you know devs love to break shit open and look inside, and I couldn't understand what was there. Your links help, and remind me of why I use moment. Cuz I don't want know what's inside there, dates suck. Moment abstracts that suck.  Thx again

Answer (score 18):

I suspect that Moment.js is working exactly like you expect it too, but console.log isn't. It prints a reference to the object, so the state you see is the current state at the time of consultation, not at the time of calling log(). Try using console.dir() instead to see the difference. Or use JSON.stringify() to get a string representation of the object, or call format() on the Moment object.

Comment: sadly, I tried console.dir and received the same results.  although thanks for telling me about console.dir.  what exactly is it doing?

Comment: Console.dir() prints the properties of the object at the time of calling. But apparently it's a non-standard Mozilla thing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir#Specifications). Sorry, didn't know that. Did you try the JSON.stringify approach? If nothing works, including the other answers here, try putting up a jsfiddle showing your problem.

Comment: this is interesting result of calling stringify  ==========start=========
 "2016-06-02T12:00:00.000Z"
==========END start=========
==========end=========
"2016-06-02T12:30:00.000Z"
==========END end========= it's not the correct time that was passed in though I passed in 6:00 PM

Comment: A matter of timezone, I assume. Did you try the format method? http://momentjs.com/ shows how to use it right on the homepage.

Comment: yes, when I output the value via format or tostring it shows the correct value but I have further calculations to do on the moment before outputing it so I need the moment to be in the correct state to work with

Comment: This was indeed the answer. Just try to print `moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` and you will see for yourself

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trusting some internal properties of the `Moment` objects (`_i`) to contain the adjusted time. It may be that manipulations are lazily applied, or that those internals are tracking the *original* time, but once you actually do anything with the object (like calling `.format()` on it), it's showing the adjusted time.

**EDIT**: or you're using an outdated version of Moment.js. It looks like version 1 exhibits similar behaviour to what you're seeing. However, you're probably looking at the most recent (v2) documentation, hence the discrepancy between documentation and observed behaviour.

> What I want is to take a moment, add 30 minutes to it and, preferably have a new moment that is 30 minutes ahead, or at least have the initial moment be 30 minutes ahead.

```
var start  = moment();
var end    = moment(start).add(30, 'minutes');

console.log( start.toString() );
console.log(   end.toString() );
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm definitely using 2.13  I updated my package ( from 2.1.0 ) deleted from node_modules and npm install'd

Comment: So the suggested code doesn't work for you? It works just fine in 2.13.0 for me.

Comment: I believe that when you call toString() or format() it displays correctly, but I need to perform, further caluclations on the moment, and it does not show what it show when you call toString, so I don't know if it's going to perform those calcs correctly

Comment: Everything here is working as designed. You just shouldn't look at any _ properties.